# Как в Django вывести несколько изображений в посте?

Tags: django

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Django вывести несколько изображений в одном посте.
Как вывести одно изображение понятно и как экземпляру класса Post привязать несколько изображений тоже.
Но как вывести несколько изображений в шаблоне не могу понять, т.к. у меня только одно поле (**body**) с телом поста, между строчками, которого нужно вставлять изображения.

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, blank=True, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True, related_name='posts')
    date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image_preview = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

********

class Images(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

**post.html**

```
{% block content %}
    <h1 class="mt-5">
        {{ post.title }}
    </h1>

    {% if post.image_preview %}
        <img src="{{ post.image_preview.url }}">
    {% endif %}

    <p>
        {{ post.body|safe }}
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: {% for image in post.image_set.all %} и так далее

Comment: Да, как перебрать все связанные с данным постом изображения я тоже понимаю.

Comment: А в чём проблема-то тогда?

Comment: Я не понимаю, как мне вставить в нужные места эти изображения в пост, ведь я вывожу тело поста целым куском.
`{{ post.body|safe }}`.
Мне нужно в самом **body** сделать какие-то метки в местах где должны быть вставлены изображения или может выводить **body** не целым куском, а как-то делить на части? И между этими частями вставлять ссылки на изображения?
Спасибо, за быстрый отклик.

Comment: А, я упустил фразу "между строчками". Я такое делал предварительным редактированием строки body в Python-коде (во вьюхе или в методе модели), но не уверен что это правильно

Comment: Попробую сейчас реализовать как Вы говорите, пока других вариантов нет.
Вроде казалось бы такое распространённое действие, вставка изображений между частями тела поста, а информации о том, как это можно реализовать найти не удается.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

По итогу: 
Вставлять изображения в 'body' можно просто с помощью ссылок на эти изображения (к примеру `<img src="/media/2020-06-09/a68eb19.jpg">`). 
Получить связанные изображения с экземпляром класса 'Post' с помощью:
`Post.objects.get(title='some_post').images_set.all()`

При создании/изменении поста в поле 'body' устанавливаем метки в тех местах, где хотим что-бы были изображения, и в модели создаем метод, который при сохранении поста заменит наши метки на ссылки на изображения.

А можно воспользоваться прекрасным редактором **django-summernote**, который с легкостью справиться с данной задачей, избавит нас от 'кучи' кода, и вдобавок даст множество возможностей для редактирования теста.

**https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote**

[image]